# Avro SerializationException is making Kafka Streams to fail and shutdown

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I am working on a project where I need to read a complex xml message from a Kafka topic, convert to equivalent avro and publish to an avro topic. Seems pretty simple and works well too with Spring Cloud Stream and Apache Kafka Streams, but the real pain is SerializationException, which is thrown if a mandatory field is missing from the xml. When it happens, all threads die and Streams shutdown. So, I am not able to process next set of records.

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=topic1, offset=0, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of AnonType_FCE in field F of AnonType_CE of union in field CE of AnonType_I in field I of AnonType_CTT of array in field C of AnonType_TT of union in field TT of AnonType_TO of union in field TO of type0
```

This is thrown when it tries to publish the converted avro and finds compatibility issue with schema registry. The trouble is, I do not have control on incoming XML messages. And, schema that I am generating is from a xsd file where backward compatibility hasn't been taken care in the previous versions (started 7 years back). Few fields do not have a default value set i.e.
`"type":"null" or "default" : null`, and if such fields are missing from xml, avroConverter puts **null** in them. These messages are causing exception.

I have looked into numerous posts where it is suggested to use **ProductionExceptionHandler** or even **DeserializationExceptionHandler**. Implemented them too, but this SerializationException is not covered in both of them. Then I found this link [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7499) where they still need to implement it (unsure if they would, as it is pending since last 3 years now !)

So, I would like to know if there is any workaround to skip corrupt record or send to a DLQ, without stopping Streams flow and continue processing incoming records. This is my code snippet below:

```
@Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, GenericRecord>> event() {
        return events -> events
                .map((key, xml) -> {
                    GenericRecord genericRecord = null;
                    try {
                        genericRecord = (GenericRecord) converterUtil.convertXmlToAvro(xml,schema);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        log.error(exception.toString());
                        sendToDlq(key, xml);
                    }
                    log.info("Converted avro msg: \n{}", genericRecord);
                    return new KeyValue<>(key, genericRecord);
                })
                 .filter((key, avroMsg) -> avroMsg != null);
    }
```

Comment: you should post the schema at least , as now we have no clue of what's happening with the given info

Comment: @aran - can't post it because of restrictions. But I posted the error, it simply happens because schema for this field doesn't have a default value ( "type":"null" or "default" : null) . So, if a field is missing in xml it is being put as null, which is being rejected at serialization time.

Comment: hmmm, I see. Anyway, if the default is null, won't the serializer also throw the exception?